# How to interpret a integer as a float

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I am trying to use a DLL written in C# to communicate with a laser. I successfully load the DLL function using the ctypes modules. The function I want to use have a declaration which look like this :

```
LONG LJV7IF_GetStorageData( LONG lDeviceId, 
                            LJV7IF_GET_STORAGE_REQ* pReq,
                            LJV7IF_STORAGE_INFO* pStorageInfo,
                            LJV7IF_GET_STORAGE_RSP* pRsp, 
                            DWORD* pdwData, 
                            DWORD dwDataSize );
```

I want to access the data via the dword pointer pdwData. The laser send its storaged data via a structure which looks like this:

```
Bytes |  Meaning  |   Types
 0-3  |   time    |    dword          
  4   |  judgment |    byte
  5   | meas info |    byte
 ...  |    ...    |    ... 
 8-11 |   data    |    float
```

This is how i use the function :

```
self.dll = WinDLL( "LJV7_IF.dll" )
self._getStoredData = self.dll.LJV7IF_GetStorageData
self._getStoredData.restype = c_int32
self._getStoredData.argstypes = [ c_int32,
                                  POINTER( GET_STORAGE_REQ ),
                                  POINTER( STORAGE_INFO ),
                                  POINTER( GET_STORAGE_RSP ),
                                  POINTER( c_uint32 ),
                                  c_uint32 ]
dataSize = 132
dataBuffer = c_uint32 * ( dataSize / 4 )
outputData_p = POINTER( c_uint32 )( dataBuffer() )
self._getStoredData( deviceID,
                     byref( myStruct ),
                     byref( storageInfo ),
                     byref( storageResponse ),
                     outputData_p ),
                     dataSize )
```

myStruct, storageInfo and storageResponse are not detailed for brevity (they are used in other DLL functions calls, and they seem to work just fine).

My problem is when I try to access `outputData_p[ 2 ]`, python return me an int, say 1066192077. Which is exactly what I asked him. But I want that int to be interpreted/converted as a float, which is supposed to be 1.1 or something like this (can't remember the exact value ). Casting it to float doesn't work ( I get 1066192077.00 ), using `hex() -> bytes() -> struct.unpack( )` either. What can I do ??

Comment: Habe you tried pack and then unpack as float?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of float you're expecting? A DWORD is just an unsigned 32 bit int, what kind of float data are you looking for? Is it scaled? If so, what's the ratio?

Comment: @eryksun so if I understand right, I pass to my function `dataBuffer = (c_uint32 * 33 )()` instead of `outputData_p` to respect the typo and once my function return I cast my _int_ buffer into a _float_ buffer using `floatBuffer = (c_float * 33).from_buffer(dataBuffer)` ?

Comment: I did write the argstypes expressions ( so I can modify it ), to follow the C# code ( which I can't change ). I did that because I though the dll would throw me an error if I directly pass an array of float when it is expecting an array of unsigned int... And the problem would be the same to read the first dword of the returned structure ( time axis ).

Comment: @eryksun both of your solution work in my case. So I thought you can post it as an answer that I will accept as the solution. Could you please detail why it works and why it should be done like this ? I am not sure I really understand the `argstypes` role in this mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: if you arrived here while searching for how to convert an integer to a single-precision float, then ignore the rest of this answer and just use the code from J.F. Sebastian's comment. It uses the struct module instead of ctypes, which is simpler and also always available, while ctypes is optionally included in Python's standard library:*

```
import struct

def float_from_integer(integer):
    return struct.unpack('!f', struct.pack('!I', integer))[0]

assert float_from_integer(1066192077) == 1.100000023841858
```

---

You can interpret an array as a different type using the ctypes [`from_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer) method. In general you can pass any object to this method that has a writeable buffer interface, not just ctypes instances -- such as `bytearray` or a NumPy array.

For example:

```python
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> int_array = (c_int * 4)(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> n_doubles = sizeof(int_array) // sizeof(c_double)
>>> array_t = c_double * n_doubles
>>> double_array = array_t.from_buffer(int_array)
```

It's still the same bytes, just reinterpreted as two 8-byte doubles:

```python
>>> bytes(double_array)
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00'
>>> double_array[:]
[4.2439915824e-314, 8.4879831653e-314]
```

Since this array was created by calling `from_buffer`, as opposed to `from_buffer_copy`, it's actually a view that shares the same buffer as the original array. For example, if you shift the last 2 integers to the front, the values in `double_array` are swapped as well:

```python
>>> int_array[:] = [3, 4, 1, 2]
>>> double_array[:]
[8.4879831653e-314, 4.2439915824e-314]
```

Note that your example code has a typo. The attribute name that defines a function's argument types is `argtypes`, not `argstypes`:

```python
self._getStoredData.argstypes = [ c_int32,
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Defining this prototype isn't strictly necessary, but it is recommended. It makes ctypes call the corresponding [`from_param`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_param) method for each each argument when the function is called. Without a prototype, the default argument handling accepts ctypes instances and automatically converts strings to `char *` or `wchar_t *` and integers to C `int` values; otherwise it raises an `ArgumentError`.

You can define the packed (i.e. without alignment padding) data record as follows:

```python
class LaserData(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('time',      c_uint),
                ('judgement', c_byte),
                ('meas_info', c_byte * 3),
                ('data',      c_float))
```

Here's an example class that defines the generic data parameter type as `POINTER(c_byte)` and returns the result as an array of records as determined by the device instance. Obviously it's only the gist of how the class should actually be defined since I know almost nothing about this API.

```python
class LJV7IF(object):
    # loading the DLL and defining prototypes should be done
    # only once, so we do this in the class (or module) definition.
    _dll = WinDLL("LJV7_IF")
    _dll.LJV7IF_Initialize()

    _dll.LJV7IF_GetStorageData.restype = c_long
    _dll.LJV7IF_GetStorageData.argtypes = (c_long,
                                           POINTER(GET_STORAGE_REQ),
                                           POINTER(STORAGE_INFO),
                                           POINTER(GET_STORAGE_RSP),
                                           POINTER(c_byte),
                                           c_uint)

    def __init__(self, device_id, record_type):
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.record_type = record_type

    def get_storage_data(self, count):
        storage_req = GET_STORAGE_REQ()
        storage_info = STORAGE_INFO()
        storage_rsp = GET_STORAGE_RSP()
        data_size = sizeof(self.record_type) * count
        data = (c_byte * data_size)()
        result = self._dll.LJV7IF_GetStorageData(self.device_id,
                                                 byref(storage_req),
                                                 byref(storage_info),
                                                 byref(storage_rsp),
                                                 data,
                                                 data_size)
        if result < 0: # assume negative means an error.
            raise DeviceError(self.device_id) # an Exception subclass.
        return (self.record_type * count).from_buffer(data)
```

For example:

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    laser = LJV7IF(LASER_DEVICE_ID, LaserData)
    for record in laser.get_storage_data(11):
        print(record.data)
```

Comment: Well, that deserve a big THANKS ! 
I didn't get why my python call wasn't type checked until you make me realise the extra s in argtype ! 
I love that `from_buffer` function. I searched for this exact features all day long before daring asking here, and you just solved it in a few minutes. _Bravo_.

Comment: You're welcome.  I prefer the new implementation of `from_buffer` in Python 3. We just rewrote it to get rid of how it was hacking the `memoryview` object, which was causing a crash in issue 25498. Now it's on a reliable footing. Python 2 still calls the old `PyObject_AsWriteBuffer`, which assumes the object will never `realloc` its buffer at a new address.

Comment: For example, in Python 2 you cannot rely on `b = bytearray(b'abc'); c = (c_char* 3).from_buffer(b); print(repr(c[:])); b.extend(b'123' * 10); print(repr(c[:]))`. The last print could be anything, and may even crash the interpreter. In Python 3, trying `b.extend` after exporting a buffer to the `memoryview` raises a `BufferError` because the export is tracked.

Comment: to answer the question in the title, you could mention: `struct.unpack('!f', struct.pack('!I', 1066192077))[0] == 1.100000023841858`

Comment: @eryksun: I know. It is for people from google lead here by the title. Either the title should be changed or the answer to the explicit (not implied) question should be present.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I added a note for anyone that simply wants to convert an integer to a float.